# Run collation with create command in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collation

I am trying to make my user model not care about case sensitivity in `email` and `username` fields. So if I try to create a user with email `Thisemail@email.com` and another one with `thisemail@email.com`, the second time it is not allowed, since the email is not unique, despite the upper case and lowercases.

My user schema is the following:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    validate: // validators here,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    validate: // validators here,
  },
  // Some other fields not case insensitive
});
```

The users are created with mongoose create function:

```
user = await User.create(userData)
```

I have tried creating a collation and it works with the `find` command directly on mongo shell.

```
db.users.createIndex({'email': 1}, {'collation': { 'locale': 'en', 'strength': 2}, 'name': 'testcollation'})
db.users.find({'email':'thisemail@email.com'}).collation({'locale':'en', 'strength': 2})
```

But when I try to append the collation to the create call, I get an error message saying collation function does not exist.

```
user = await User.create(userData).collation({ "locale": "en", "strength": 2 });
```

Following this link, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-collation, I would expect this to work:

```
User.create(...).collation is not a function
```

Any idea how to run the collation with the create function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique) on `email` with that collation, that should disallow creating duplicate emails at the database level:

> `db.users.createIndex({'email': 1}, { 'collation': { 'locale': 'en', 'strength': 2 }, unique: true, 'name': 'testcollation' })`

Creating this index should make your duplicate `User.create` calls fail. The Mongoose Schema `unique` option creates a similar index automatically, but it won't be aware of your desired collation. I'm unsure whether there's a way of setting up Mongoose schema settings to get it to create your desired index.

You can also set the collation on the collection level in your [`createCollection` call](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#mongodb-method-db.createCollection). You can't modify an existing collection to have a different collation though: this will only work on initial collection creation.

Comment: So having a unique index + another index with a case sensitivity does not do the trick? It has to be an index having both, is that right?

Comment: Yup, you need to have a unique index with the collation that you want. Otherwise, one index only enforces uniqueness but doesn't care about collation, and the other index only has collation and will otherwise behave as a regular index and just be useful for queries.

Comment: Just one note, I still need to set the collation when performing a search in MongoDB, otherwise it will not match documents when performing finds with case "insensitivity".

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use collation with create since it only works with a `find` cursor

> Specifies the collation for the cursor returned by the db.collection.find(). To use, append to the db.collection.find()

For your scenario you may want to use a pre save hook

e.g.

```
schema.pre("save", function(next) {
  // ...do something with "this"
  next();
});
```

Comment: So I should call `find` with the collation in the pre save hook and if a match is found (email already exists with different capital letters) then fail? Is there any way to make this work with only one DB call?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to query first, create or error if there's a duplicate. In your case, I would use a simple regex to check the case insensitivity.

```
const checkUserDuplicate = await User.find({ email: { $regex: `${userData.email}`, $options: 'i' }});
if (checkUserDuplicate && checkUserDuplicate.email === userData.email) {
  return next(res.status(500).json('Email already in use'));
} else {
  const user = await User.create(userData);
  res.status(201).json(user);
}
```

According to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) this type of middleware should run after save.

```
UserSchema.post('save', function (error, doc, next) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoServerError' && error.code === 11000) {
    next(console.log('Email address already in use'))
  }
  else {
    next()
  }
})
```

You could then add `lowercase: true` to the user.email schema property which always calls `.toLowerCase()` on the value.

Comment: So there's no way of doing this with one db call? I'm not worried about a race condition, but just FIY your solution does not fix them. I mean, there could be a race in there anyways.

Comment: You are correct, I see that now. Made a few updates to my original.

Answer (score 0):

To run collation with create command in mongoose, you need to specify the collation option in the schema definition or in the create method. Collation is a feature that allows you to specify the rules for comparing strings in different languages and alphabets. For example, you can use collation to make your user model not care about case sensitivity in email and username fields.

### Explanation

Mongoose is a popular object data modeling (ODM) library for MongoDB, a NoSQL database. Mongoose allows you to define schemas for your collections, which are like blueprints for your documents. Schemas can have various options, such as validators, indexes, hooks, virtuals, and collation.

Collation is an option that lets you define the language-specific rules for sorting and matching strings. For example, you can use collation to make your user model ignore the case of the email and username fields, so that Thisemail@email.com and thisemail@email.com are considered the same. You can also use collation to sort strings according to different alphabets, such as Arabic, Cyrillic, or Latin.

To use collation in mongoose, you need to specify the collation option in the schema definition or in the create method. The collation option is an object that has several properties, such as locale, strength, caseLevel, and caseFirst. You can find the full list of collation properties and their meanings in the MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/

For example, to make your user model not care about case sensitivity in email and username fields, you can use the following collation option:

```py
collation = {
  'locale': 'en', # use English as the language
  'strength': 2, # ignore case and diacritics, such as accents
  'caseLevel': False, # do not distinguish between base characters and case variants
  'caseFirst': 'off' # do not sort uppercase before lowercase or vice versa
}
```

You can then apply this collation option to your user schema or to your create method. For example:

```py
# define the user schema with the collation option
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {type: String, required: True, unique: True},
  username: {type: String, required: True, unique: True},
  password: {type: String, required: True}
}, {collation: collation})

# create the user model from the schema
User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

# create a new user with the collation option
User.create({
  email: 'Thisemail@email.com',
  username: 'Thisuser',
  password: '123456'
}, {collation: collation}, (err, user) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    console.log(user)
  }
})
```

### Examples

Here are some examples of how collation works in mongoose:

- If you create a user with email Thisemail@email.com and username Thisuser, and then try to create another user with email thisemail@email.com and username thisuser, you will get a duplicate key error, because the collation option makes them equivalent.
- If you create a user with email Thisemail@email.com and username Thisuser, and then try to find them by email thisemail@email.com or username thisuser, you will get the same user, because the collation option makes them match.
- If you create a user with email Thisemail@email.com and username Thisuser, and then try to sort them by email or username, you will get the same order regardless of the case, because the collation option makes them equal.

Comment: Whenever I try to call create with collation like you showed, I get an error with the validators: `User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required., username: Path `username` is required., email: Path `email` is required. at model.Document.invalidate`. Any ideas? Do I need to add the collation always in the schema or adding it just in the create is enough?

Comment: Btw, I get that error but the document is saved to DB anyways.